# Define watermark in pdf using rotativa

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, rotativa

I'm using Rotativa to generate some pdf's in a mvc application, now, I need to define an image as a watermark for the pdf, I was trying setting some custom css properties to the body tag, but in this case. I need to define the margin as 0, also I have a custom switch for a footer and with the margin 0 this is a problem.

I'm looking for a way t define a watermark, maybe using a custom switch.

Anyone knows if is possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

In your view put this HTML

```
<div class="watermark" style="background: url('../Images/watermark.png');"></div>
```

Also, add this style to your css file (or in a style section inside you view)

```
.watermark {
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0.25;
}
```